# Android emulator dont want to work?

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium

I have a problem launching the android simulator on Titanium Studio;

I did everything i should do, verified the variable environment, ran the AVD Manager and it works (alone), but when launching the 'hello world' application, nothing works! it only works on web navigator?

Here is the error:

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.2, Titanium SDK version 3.1.3.GA     Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
[INFO] :   Running emulator process: python  "C:\Users\toto\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.3.GA\android\builder.py"  "emulator" "KitchenSink" "C:\Users\toto\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk" "C:\Users\toto\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Kitchen Sink" "com.appcelerator.kitchensink" "2" "WVGA854" "armeabi-v7a"
[INFO] :   Running build process:  python "C:\Users\toto\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.3.GA\android\builder.py" "simulator" "KitchenSink" "C:\Users\toto\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk" "C:\Users\toto\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Kitchen Sink" "com.appcelerator.kitchensink" "2" "WVGA854"
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[INFO] logfile = C:\Users\toto\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Kitchen Sink\build.log
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
```

[image: picture one]

And here is on a web page, it works!

[image: web page]

Comment: Remove screenshot of your IDE and just copy&paste Error Log, otherwise it's not readable.

Comment: Thx, that's much clearer. Solution should be pretty easy, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install required Android SDKs?

Titanium SDK requires pretty old version of Android SDK (<=2.3.3). Start of with checking this matrix and then go through whole tutorial to make sure that all components are installed properly: [Titanium Documentation: Installing the Android SDK](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK-section-29004851_InstallingtheAndroidSDK-AndroidSDK/TargetAndroidPlatform).

Comment: thank you, old version? do you mean that i will install an old version of android?

Comment: I mean you need to install Android **SDK** with version 2.3.3 (or older if you are not using latest Titanium SDK). Do **not** change anything on your device.

Comment: but what i dont understand, is why i got the simulator working when it's not titanium that calls him? i thought what titanium will do is a simple script invoking the simulator, and then it will put the application inside the simulator? but it seems that  it cant run the simulator  at  all